# непонятная ошибка в программе

Tags: c#, строки

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public static class Kata
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DuplicateEncode("(( @"));
    }
    public static string DuplicateEncode(string word)
    {
        string str = "";
        foreach (char i in word.ToLower())
        {
           /* Console.WriteLine(i+i.ToString());*/  
            if (i.ToString() != "(" || i.ToString() != ")")
            {
                if ((Regex.Matches(word, i.ToString()).Count) == 1)
                {
                    str += "(";
                }
                else
                {
                    str += ")";
                }
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

код должен возвращать строку из скобок, которые расставляются по следующему принципу - если буква/знак/пробел встречаются 1 раз ставится "(", если больше одного раза, ставится ")"
но при обработке строки "(( @" компилятор требует закрыть скобки. почему?

Comment: Нет, компилятор не ругается. Этот код компилируется без ошибок. / Ругается парсер регулярных выражений. На вход ему подаётся некорректный шаблон регулярного выражения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как не банально прозвучит, но ошибка в вашей логике. Я вижу что Вы пытались избежать обработки скобок, но тут Вы допустили небольшую но повлиявшую на результат оплошность. Дело в том что проверка через `||` это настоящая лазейка для бага. Чтобы ее прикрыть достаточно заменить `||` на `&&`.

Давайте попробуем на примере собак, кошек и попугаев. Собак и кошек мы не хотим пропускать.

```
if (animal.type != "собака" || animal.type != "кошка" ) {
   // какой-то код
}
```

Теперь представьте что у нас на входе собака, первая часть условия явно запретит

```
animal.type != "собака" // false
```

Но вторая разрешит ведь

```
"собака" != "кошка" // true
```

а мы обрабатываем `||` т.е. если хоть одна часть true, то мы выполняем тело условия.

В случае если мы используем `&&` пройдут только попугаи.

Что касается самой ошибки, она не непонятная, просто в регулярках которые Вы пытались использовать скобки - это часть синтаксиса, если они не экранированы, по этой причине Вы и получали ошибку, это ошибка паттерна регулярки, скобки в регулярках отвечают за группу.

Иными словами ошибку вызывает такая запись:

```
Regex.Matches(word, "(").Count == 1
```

А такая бы не вызвала:

```
Regex.Matches(word, "\(").Count == 1 // с экранированием
```

Как подсказал @AlexanderPetrov в комментарии код можно было бы записать таким образом:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static class Kata
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DuplicateEncode("(( @"));
    }
    public static string DuplicateEncode(string word)
    {
        string str = "";
        foreach (char i in word.ToLower())
        {
            if ((Regex.Matches(word, Regex.Escape(i.ToString())).Count) == 1)
            {
                str += "(";
            }
            else
            {
                str += ")";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

и результат был бы таким:`))((`

Comment: Экранирование можно делать методом `Regex.Escape`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ну или таким образом, спасибо. В данном случае я хотел показать сырую строку.